# Java Newbie error: cannot find symbol

Tags: java, switch-statement

I want to allow the person to type for example 112 into the console, press enter, and then end up with "Hello, Mars." as the answer.

I'm getting stuck on "error: cannot find symbol".

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int n1 = userVar;

        switch ( userVar )
        {
            case 111:
                System.out.println("Hello, Earth.");
                break;
            case 112:
                System.out.println("Hello, Mars.");
                break;
            case 113:
                System.out.println("Hello, Jupiter.");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Hello, Space.");
        }

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        n1 = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Now, I've tried changing the int to

```
int userVar;
```

and

```
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        userVar = keyboard.nextInt();
```

But ultimately got stuck with an "error: variable userVar might not have been initialized". Note that I am doing this on Ideone.

Comment: Remember that local variables, unlike member variables, *don't* get initialised for you - you've got to make sure that there aren't any routes through your method that leave that variable uninitialised. The easiest way to do that is to do as Eran suggested and just initialise it immediately to some default value.

Comment: When you want help with debugging, you need to show us the code *exactly* as it is in the state that you want debugged.  You show us the initial code, and say that you made some changes.  But you don't show us what the code looks like *after* the changes.

Comment: IDE has it's uses, but you need to get yourself a proper environment with a debugger otherwise you're not going to be able to debug it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, give `userVar` a default value :

```
int userVar = 0;
```

Then attempt to assign to it user input :

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
userVar = keyboard.nextInt();
```

Comment: Getting a java.util.NoSuchElementException error, but I think that's just Ideone giving an issue. Anyway, thank you for the help! I'll give it a go at home on a proper IDE.

Comment: @HAXORvault You'll get a NoSuchElementException if you are entering non numeric characters, since keyboard.nextInt() expects an integer to be entered.

Comment: Ah ok, yeah, Ideone doesn't have a console to enter any characters, hence why it's running into a brick wall, but at least I am getting "Hello, Space." as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class main(){
    public static void main(String []args){
       int userVar = 0;
       System.out.print("ENTER NO > ");
       Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
       userVar = keyboard.nextInt(); //The given input stoted in userVar.
      // Now Apply Switch-case :)
```

}
}